# How do I change the tintColor of UIDragPreviewParameters

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdropdelegate, uicollectionviewdragdelegate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMs8.jpg)

How do I change the number's background color to red?

UIDragPreviewParameters only provide a background color to modify the translucent cell.

I have a collection view and conform the dragDelegate and dropDelegate.

here is the method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    print("itemsForBeginning")
    return [UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragPreviewParametersForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
    print("dragPreviewParametersForItemAt")
    let s = UIDragPreviewParameters()
    s.backgroundColor = .orange
    return s
}
```

Comment: can you add code that used ?@yxk

Comment: It might not be possible. iOS itself creates the badge and updates its color depending on whether a drop is not possible (grey), possible (blue) or possible and will make a copy (green with a plus sign).